# Node.js Cookie Parser stops page from loading

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm creating a website using Node.js and Express. I'm using `cookie-parser` to create a cookie to store a sequence.
I'm also using `express.Router()` for routing.

When I use `router.use(cookieParser)` and try to load the page it never loads. I have commented this line out and it works again. I'm not getting any error messages.

Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

router.use(cookieParser);

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var i = 0;
    //shuffle the sequence array
    while (i++ < 10) {
      const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
      const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

      if (a !== b) {
        var temp = sequence[a];
        sequence[a] = sequence[b];
        sequence[b] = temp;
      }
    };
  res.cookie('sequence', JSON.stringify(sequence));
  res.redirect('./article');
  console.log(sequence);
  //res.redirect('./article');
});



module.exports = router;
```

This happens in every single one of my routs.
Does anybody know why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router method should be use when  you are creating new route path specific signature of route url. You should set the cookie parser object  to express object. Try this below code and see.

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
var i = 0;
//shuffle the sequence array
while (i++ < 10) {
  const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

  if (a !== b) {
    var temp = sequence[a];
    sequence[a] = sequence[b];
    sequence[b] = temp;
  }
};
res.cookie('sequence', JSON.stringify(sequence));
res.redirect('./article');
console.log(sequence);
//res.redirect('./article');
});



module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 10):

Fix by

```
router.use(cookieParser());
```

instead of

```
router.use(cookieParser);
```

on code line number 4